# bootstrap Invalid CSS selector button::-moz-focus-inner

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

My editor is rubymine5.4.3
I download bootstrap 2.3.2 on official page, when I use it in below index.html(I hit shift + f9(debug this html))

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>ex</title>
  <meta name="description" content="ex">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/bootstrap.css"/>
  <script type="text/javascript" src="js/jquery.js"></script>
  <script type="text/javascript" src='js/bootstrap.js'></script>
  <script type="text/javascript">

  </script>
</head>
<body>

</body>
</html>
```

get a below errors:

```
Invalid CSS selector: button::-moz-focus-inner,
input::-moz-focus-inner lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:130
Invalid CSS selector: input:-moz-placeholder,
textarea:-moz-placeholder   lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:1239
Invalid CSS selector: input:-ms-input-placeholder,
textarea:-ms-input-placeholder  lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:1244
Invalid CSS selector: button.btn::-moz-focus-inner,
input[type="submit"].btn::-moz-focus-inner  lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:3564
Invalid CSS selector: .navbar-inverse .navbar-search .search-query:-moz-placeholder lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:4891
Invalid CSS selector: .navbar-inverse .navbar-search .search-query:-ms-input-placeholder    lib/ex/template/ex/css/bootstrap.css:4895
nimabi  lib/ex/template/ex/index.html:11
```

Answer (score 0):

The -moz prefix is only recognized by Mozilla browsers (Firefox). The -ms prefix is only recognized by IE. You can safely ignore those errors.